# How to install Ruby 2.2.3 on elementary OS (Freya)?

Tags: release-freya, software-installation

As far as I am concerned `sudo apt-get install ruby-full` only installs Ruby 1.9.3, which is an old stable release.

How can I install the latest, stable Ruby release (v. 2.2.3) on elementary OS (Freya)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation using `rvm`:

Install `curl`:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Install `rvm`: ([secure installation](https://rvm.io/rvm/security))

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

\curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer

\curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer.asc

gpg --verify rvm-installer.asc &&

bash rvm-installer stable
```

Note : If `gpg --keyserver` fails use,(first line)

```
 curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
```

Install `ruby`

```
 rvm get stable --autolibs=enable
 rvm install 2.2.3
 rvm --default use ruby-2.2.3
```

Note: To list available ruby versions run `sudo rvm list known` and select the desired version.

Comment: Brilliant. I installed Ruby using rvm. It worked just fine for me. I had to to type 'rvm install ruby-2.2.3' but other than that everything worked right away. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Install all dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
  ```

Now select any one of the methods:

1.Using `rbenv`

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash

rbenv install 2.2.3
rbenv global 2.2.3
ruby -v
```

---

2.using `rvm` (detailed steps [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/how-to-install-ruby-2-2-3-on-elementary-os-freya/2582#2582))

```
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm install 2.2.3
rvm use 2.2.3 --default
ruby -v
```

---

3.From `source`

```
cd
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.3.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-2.2.3.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.2.3/
./configure
make
sudo make install
ruby -v
```

<sub>reference [here](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04)</sub>