# Installing Ruby On Rails on Elementary OS Shows build failed errors

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Ruby On Rails on my Elementary OS installed machine. But after giving this line of code `rbenv install 2.3.0`. 
 The Following errors comes into my terminal.

`Downloading ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2
error: failed to download ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2`
`BUILD FAILED (elementary OS 0.3.2 using ruby-build 20160426-25-gabb7d1d)`
`Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20160526021040.24601
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20160526021040.24601.log`
`Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20160526021040.24601 ~
curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104`

Can anyone please tell me, how can i overcome from this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can install ruby with:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Afterwards you can install rails with:

```
gem install rails
```

Since rails is actually a gem you can install it this way and afterwards you can generate your rails project and add other gems via the Gemfile.

I did it this way and I am currently developing on rails using elementary os.

Comment: should i mention the ruby version on `sudo apt-get install ruby` to `sudo apt-get install ruby 2.3.0`

Comment: Only if you want a version other than the latest release. Either way it will work.

Comment: and what about the mysql?

Comment: It is likely that you already have mysql installed. Use: `mysql -V` to check your current version.

Comment: In case you don't here is a link to the installation instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

If you still have problem with installing ruby (I had with Jorge's method, as it would install me older version), try with instructions from this thread [How to install Ruby 2.2.3 on elementary OS (Freya)?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/how-to-install-ruby-2-2-3-on-elementary-os-freya) it helped me and now I have the latest version of ruby.